# Как в WDIO Testrunner + Mocha подключить два компилятора, CoffeeScript и Babel?

Tags: babel, coffeescript, mocha

Я пишу тесты на `CoffeeScript` с использованием `Webdriver.io` и `mocha`. Код обрабатывается с помощью компилятора CoffeeScript.

В проекте, который я разрабатываю, было принято решение перейти на синтаксис ES6. Чтобы обеспечить поддерживаемость кода, написанного ранее, был подключен компилятор `Babel`, который преобразует неподдерживаемые синтаксические конструкции (например, import) в поддерживаемые (require). Однако Mocha не предусматривает возможности запуска двух компиляторов одновременно (по крайней мере, такие данные я нашел в сети).

Конечно, можно пойти обходным путем: скопмилировать файлы с помощью компилятора  CoffeeScript, сохранить их во временную папку, а Mocha сконфигурировать с компилятором Babel таким образом, чтобы Babel компилировал преобразованные файлы из временной папки:

```
coffee -c test/*.coffee
mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register
```

Однако это не самое красивое решение: приходится использовать две команды вместо одной, следить за папкой с временными файлами и проч. Хотелось бы как-то выполнить CoffeeScript-фйалы с помощью Babel одной командой без использования временных папок и файлов. Пока что вся информация, найденная мною в интернете, сводится к тому, что это невозможно (примерно такая информация https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/4969 мне попадалась уже неоднократно). Однако может быть способы всё-таки есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная информация по данному вопросу была найдена здесь: https://www.npmjs.com/package/coffee-babel. Пакет NPM coffee-babel решает описанную проблему.

Единственный нюанс: для корректной работы пакета в файле wdio.conf.js в настройках компилятора Mocha необходимо подключить пакет coffee-babel. Делается это следующим образом:

```
mochaOpts: {
    ...
    ...
    require: ['coffee-babel'],
}
```